# Saint Elmo's fire on the ISS? What are these green glowing balls of plasma on a solar panel? Dangerous?

Tags: identify-this-object, plasma

This [tweet](https://twitter.com/marsrader/status/1154386876830236678) says:

> Almost the entire population of Egypt lives within a few miles of the Nile.

But my eye is on the green glowing balls on what looks like it might be a solar panel.

**Question:** What are all these little green glowing balls of (presumably) plasma on this (presumably) solar panel on the ISS? Saint Elmo's fire? Its space station equivalent? What exactly causes it? It looks like an electrical discharge but that's not something you'd normally want to be doing on solar panels, wouldn't there be a preferred pointy thing to discharge the ISS with?

See answers to [How do spacecraft measure their own charge?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20160/12102)

[image: glowing green balls of plasm a on the ISS]

[image: glowing green balls of plasm a on the ISS]

Comment: Reflections of internal LEDs.  Not associated with the solar arrays.  Remember the truck parked behind the shuttle? https://space.stackexchange.com/a/8363/6944

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes indeed I do!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an internal reflection.  I wish I knew of what exactly, but here's the same line of green LEDs in a different picture.  Some gadget in the cupola.

[image]

I am not promising this is the source, but the Robotics Workstation (mounted in the cupola) has a lot of green LED illuminated buttons on it and you can see them reflecting all over the place here.

[image]

Comment: yes indeed, that panel looks awfully suspicious.

Comment: The same one Earthy was standing on.

Comment: [What is Earthy controlling in the ISS cupola?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34731/12102) feel free to add it back in

Comment: The refractive index is a US government conspiracy...

Comment: An international cabal - the Canadians built the Workstation!