# MATLAB Simple Elliptical Orbits with J2 perturbation and drag

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit

For some reason I need to build a Elliptical Orbits satellite dynamic model by myself, in here I am using MATALB.
The model its fine before (I think the J2 effect part works well) I add drag effect on it, the Altitude became ascent, it should descent by time right? 
Here are some equation I am using:
[image: Drag]

And the simulator result:
[image]
[image]

Drag part code:

```
% Calculate the drag acceleration
    v_rel_mag = norm(v_rel);
    rho = atmospheric_density(norm(r_icrf) - RE); % call to your atmospheric density function
    a_drag = -0.5 * Cd * A / m *  rho * v_rel_mag^2 * (v_rel / v_rel_mag)
    
    % Total acceleration
    a_total = a_gravity + a_J2 + a_drag;

    % Output derivative of state vector
    Ydot = [vvector; a_total];
end

function rho = atmospheric_density(altitude)
    % Simple exponential atmosphere model (or use a more complex model)
    rho0 = 3.614*10^-14; % kg/m^3 at sea level
    H = 8500; % scale height in meters
    rho = rho0 * exp(-((altitude-700) / 88.667));
end
```

[Full code][4] https://pastecode.io/s/pcw2mvjb

Can anyone help me? thank you!

Comment: What is the integration scheme? Matlab's builtin `ode45` or similar?

Comment: @AJN I am using ODE23s

Comment: I think there's a nearly-identical existing question on the site which makes it clearer that the problem is that the satellite is seeming to ascend because of atmospheric drag. I believe AJN's indication that integration precision issues can cause that was the resolution to that problem; I don't have time at the moment to figure out which question it was, but you'd be well-served looking for it on this site yourself.

Answer (score 3):

#### When coding/scripting a new project, always independently test each of your functions. Don't just run the whole thing at once.

Also, the single scale height is useless at orbital altitudes. Above about 100 km the fall-off is MUCH slower.

- [see this answer to *What orbit would a space station need to stay in orbit for N years?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37597/12102)
- [Why does Earth's atmospheric density have a big "knee" around 100 km? Is there a good analytical approximation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21604/12102)
- [Would the >100 km "knee" in Earth's atmosphere still be where MFP exceeded scale height if it were pure Ne or Ar?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49712/12102)
- [How many solar system bodies have "knees" in their atmospheres?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49676/12102)

[image: atmospheric knee at 100 km]

"`rho0 = 3.614*10^-14; % kg/m^3` at sea level" seems way off. It's about 1.3 mg/cm^3 and so about 1 .3 kg/m^3. And two lines below that you don't even use the scale height `H` (which looks good) but instead use `88.667` and have no idea what that number is.

Your Matlab:

```
function rho = atmospheric_density(altitude)
    % Simple exponential atmosphere model (or use a more complex model)
    rho0 = 3.614*10^-14; % kg/m^3 at sea level
    H = 8500; % scale height in meters
    rho = rho0 * exp(-((altitude-700) / 88.667));
end
```

My Python:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def atmospheric_density(altitude):
    # Simple exponential atmosphere model (or use a more complex model)
    rho0 = 3.614E-14 # kg/m^3 at sea level
    H = 8500 # scale height in meters
    rho = rho0 * np.exp(-((altitude - 700) / 88.667))
    return rho

def atmospheric_density_fixed(altitude):
    rho0 = 1.3 # kg/m^3 at sea level
    H = 8500 # scale height in meters
    rho = rho0 * np.exp(-((altitude - 700) / H))  # DIVIDE BY H
    return rho

alti = np.linspace(0, 4E+05, 1000) # sea level to 400 km

density = atmospheric_density(alti)
density_fixed  = atmospheric_density_fixed(alti)

densities = density, density_fixed
labels = 'original', 'fixed'

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

for den, label in zip(densities, labels):
    ax.plot(alti/1000, den, label=label)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel('altitude (km)')
ax.set_ylabel('density (kg/m^3)')
ax.set_ylim(1E-30, 10)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]